# Looking for a short story with time-loop plot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I remember the plot as follows: a guy is almost done building time-machine, then on some day he sees his girlfriend die in an accident, so he rushes to the machine and sends himself couple of hours to the past, when he finds out he cannot move a muscle or do anything and is forced to repeat the same actions. However the story end with him noticing that some leaves fall differently in the wind, implying there is yet hope.

Comment: How long ago did you read it? Was it in an anthology or a magazine?

Comment: I guess it was about 8 or 10 years ago and it was in an anthology

Answer (score 1):

"The Time Machine" 2002 is the year I think you're looking for, there are several other versions also with slightly different plots.

Comment: That seems to be a film, not a short story. And it doesn't really fit the details given in the question.

Comment: *The Time Machine* is a novella by HG Wells, but it doesn't match well.

Comment: The 2002 remake does contain that particular plot point.  The inventor created the machine to save the girlfriend, so that's the one thing it won't "let" him do as doing so would prevent its creation.